# SQL query multiple tables with different column names that contain the same data

Tags: sql, oracle, jira-plugin

I am attempting to query multiple tables from the JIRA application, we are running a Oracle DB. What I am attempting to do is write a single query that can total the number of user names  and how many times it see's a single user name. I can do this on a per statistic basis (comments, issue history, etc...) but have yet to find a way to be able to combine my queries in a meaningful way....

```
-- Comment total by user query:
select author, count(actiontype) as total
from jiraaction 
group by author
order by total desc;
-- Jira issues reported by user query:
select reporter, count(reporter) as total
from jiraissue
group by reporter
Order by total desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union all` and regroup:

```
select author, sum(authors) as NumAuthors, sum(Reporters) as NumReporters,
       (sum(authors) + sum(reporters) ) as Total
from ((select author, count(actiontype) as authors, 0 as reporters
       from jiraaction 
       group by author
      ) union all
      (select reporter, 0, count(reporter)
       from jiraissue
       group by reporter
      )
     ) ar
group by author
Order by total desc;
```

Comment: You miss the group by for the author column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION operation. Like this:

```
Select a.author, sum(a.total) as total
  from ( 
         select author, count(actiontype) as total
           from jiraaction 
          group by author
          UNION ALL
         select reporter, count(reporter) as total
           from jiraissue
          group by reporter
        ) a
 order by a.total desc
```